# SQL Server stored procedure returning correct number of rows, but all rows are the same

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ssms

Not sure where the problem is here... I have a stored procedure written that (when executed within SQL Server Mgmt. Studio) returns results I expect to see:

```
USE [DataViewer]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[DV_GetPSCTreeNodes]    Script Date: 08/10/2014 1:48:03 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Me!>
-- Description: <Used by data viewer GUI.>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DV_GetPSCTreeNodes]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

    @iNodeLevel int,
    @iParentNodeId bigint

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sQuery varchar (2000)

    IF @iNodeLevel >= 5

    RETURN

    ELSE

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SET @sQuery = 'SELECT * FROM DataView.dbo.v_Tree
    WHERE L' + CAST((@iNodeLevel + 1) AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'ID IS NULL
    AND L' + CAST((@iNodeLevel) AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'ID = ' + CAST((@iParentNodeId)
    AS VARCHAR(10))

    EXEC (@sQuery)
END
```

As mentioned, if I run this in SMSS, I get the expected results.

However, if I run this through the service I have set up, I get the correct amount of records back, but they are all duplicates of the first row (and I can look at the table and know I am getting duplicates). If I try new params and get 15 distinct rows back in SSMS, my webpage will show 15 rows of repeated row 1 data.

Here is the call from my Client:

```
List<v_PowerSystemCIMTree> list = null;
DVServiceClient proxy = new DVServiceClient();

try
{
    list = proxy.DV_GetPSCTreeNodes(2,325550).ToList(); //2 and 325550 are just hardcoded to 
                                                        //check to see if it's working
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.GetType().FullName);
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    proxy.Close();
}
return View(list);
```

Which calls my Service:

```
readonly DataViewerEntities _Context = new DataViewerEntities();

public List<DataViewer_DAL.v_PowerSystemCIMTree> DV_GetPSCTreeNodes(int firstParam,
long secondParam)
{
    return _Context.DV_GetPSCTreeNodes(firstParam,secondParam).ToList();
}
```

Why the heck would I get one result set in the Management Studio, but repeated data on my webpage?

Comment: Known issue: since you're selecting from a **view** which doesn't have a defined **primary key**, Entity Framework will use all non-nullable columns as the "entity key". If it reads a second row from the view that has the *same entity key*, it will just repeat the first row already read - it will **not** look at the other, remaining columns....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Known issue: since you're selecting from a **view** which doesn't have a defined **primary key**, Entity Framework will use all non-nullable columns as the "entity key".

If EF reads a second row from the view that has the **same entity key** (same values in all non-nullable columns), it will just repeat the first row already read - it will **not** look at the other, remaining columns....

So you just need to either add the primary key for the underlying table(s) to the view's columns, tweak the EF data model to **explicitly** define an "entity key" for the view, or you need to add an artificial, unique column (like a `ROW_NUMBER()`) to your view and make sure it's non-nullable and thus part of the EF "derived" entity key

Comment: Thank you so much! You undoubtedly just saved me hours at work tomorrow.